# Swift 3 - Check if a string exist inside an array and sort it

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, detection

I have this special array `var myArray : [Array<String>] = [["a"],["b"],["c"]]`
I want to detect if `"a"` is already inside `myArray`

and after i would like to sort my array alphabetically but i havn't found any function to do all these things for my array

Comment: Do your inner arrays always contain 1 string, or could there be multiple?

Comment: @vacawama myArray contain multiple string but i want to detect only one string

Comment: When you say sort alphabetically, what would be the expected result for this array `[["c", "a"], ["e", "b"], ["d"]]`?

Comment: @vacawama yeah this array can be like you said

Comment: If you sort that array I gave you, what result are you expecting?

Comment: @vacawama i expect this `[["a","c"], ["b","e"], ["d"]]`

Comment: @vacawama sorry to inconvenience you but is it possible to save/resore myArray with `UserDefaults.standard`

Comment: `let ud = UserDefaults.standard;
        
        let array = [["a", "c"], ["d", "e"], ["b"]];
        
        ud.set(array, forKey: "myArray");
        
        if let array2 = ud.value(forKey: "myArray") as? [[String]] {
            print(array2)
        }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find if your `[[String]]` contains `"a"`, you can use `contains` twice:

```
var myArray : [Array<String>] = [["a"],["b"],["c"]]

if myArray.contains(where: { $0.contains("a") }) {
    print("a found")
}
```

---

To sort the inner arrays, apply `map` to the outer array and sort each element:

```
var myArray : [Array<String>] = [["c", "a"], ["e", "b"], ["d"]]

let sorted = myArray.map { $0.sorted() }

print(sorted)
```

> ```
> [["a", "c"], ["b", "e"], ["d"]]
> ```